# GeoServer HTTP error 404 at start up on OSX

Tags: geoserver, java

My copy of GeoServer is showing an HTTP error 404 at start up. I can't figure out what's wrong and didn't find any useful help online either. Here is the log from GeoServer:

```
WARNING: Module not found [ssl]
2017-01-13 14:58:16.310:INFO::startup executor: Logging initialized @16310ms
2017-01-13 14:58:16.664:INFO:oejs.Server:startup executor: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
2017-01-13 14:58:16.700:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:startup executor: Deployment monitor [file:/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Java/webapps/] at interval 1
2017-01-13 14:58:17.955:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:startup executor: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2017-01-13 14:58:18.415:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:startup executor: FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7796e2d9{/geoserver,file:/Applications/GeoServer.app/Contents/Java/webapps/geoserver/,STARTING}{/geoserver}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$ProductionHandler.start(GeoServerConsole.java:129)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$Frame$8.run(GeoServerConsole.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-01-13 14:58:18.417:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:startup executor: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextInitialized(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$ProductionHandler.start(GeoServerConsole.java:129)
    at org.geoserver.console.GeoServerConsole$Frame$8.run(GeoServerConsole.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-01-13 14:58:18.555:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:startup executor: Started ServerConnector@486d04a9{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

My configuration is the following:

- GeoServer version 2.10.1 ("Mac OS X Installer")
- Mac OS X 10.11.6 on a Macbook Air 11''
- Java website says I have Java 8 update 111, `java -version` on Terminal says `Java version 1.6.0_65`

I tried to download the software again but the error persists.

Comment: That looks ok (those are warnings so you can ignore them) - what happens when you go to http://localhost:8080/geoserver ?

Comment: There's an error 404 message: "Problem accessing /geoserver. Reason: Not Found"

Comment: can't tell what's up with just that part of the log

Comment: I pasted the whole log here...

Answer (score 1):

If you have java8 installed, which is a must have for this version of GeoServer 2.10.1. you need to tell Tomcat what version of Java it is looking for. Also I think your terminal should also give your some feedback that you are using Java8 version.

This is what I did in Tomcat v.7 in Linux:

```
`sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat7`
```

Change line with JAVA_HOME to path where your Java8 is located. My was at:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

[Installing GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224461/installing-geoserver)