# Installing GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, installation, ubuntu, tomcat

I have edited my post to make it look more clear.

I wanted to upgrade GeoServer from v.2.7.1 to v.2.10.1 on Ubunutu 14.4. I deployed v.2.7.1 in Tomcat Web Application Manager. I have downloaded v2.10.1, geoserver-2.10.1-war.zip and unzipped it in */var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*. Tomcat Web Application Manager is saying that geoserver is not running, http://myhostname:8080/geoserver/web returned HTTP Status 404.

server.xml in */var/lib/tomcat7/conf* looks like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then I have undeployed v.2.10.1 and deployed v.2.7.1 a-g-a-i-n in the same configuration and it worked fine.

---

**Edit:**

I figured out that v.2.10.1 needs java8 to run, and previously I had java 7 running with tomcat7. I have uninstalled both of them and then install new versions java version "1.8.0_111" and Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04 where in `tomcat.conf` I changed line `env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre` to env `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre`.

So now I have:

```
opt
├── gwc
├── java
└── tomcat

/opt/tomcat/webapps
├── docs
├── examples
├── geoserver
├── host-manager
├── manager
└── ROOT
```

Tomcat Web Application Manager says that GeoServer is running, however myhostname:8080/geoserver/web returned HTTP Status 404.

with `catalina.sh run` I get this:

```
$ ./catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.435 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 9 2016 08:48:39 UTC
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.39.0
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.16.0-30-generic
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.590 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.605 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.607 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.609 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 555 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.645 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.971 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver has finished in 325 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.971 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.988 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 16 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:22.988 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.216 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 228 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.216 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.313 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 97 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.314 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.330 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 16 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.330 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.342 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 12 ms
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.345 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.350 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
14-Jan-2017 16:55:23.351 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 741 ms
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51777/discussion-on-question-by-newbie-girl-installing-geoserver).

Answer (score 1):

To run GeoServer 2.10+ you must make sure that tomcat is running in a Java 8 JVM. To see if this is your issue check in `/var/log/tomcat/localhost.2017-01-13/log` (with today's date) and if you see anything that says `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` like:

```
Jan 13, 2017 1:07:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 13, 2017 1:07:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4925)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5504)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On Ubuntu 14 I found that the `init.d/tomcat7` script was hardcoded to look for Java 7 or 6. To fix this (after I had [installed Java 8 and set it using the alternatives system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04)) I edited (as root) `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` and found the section that was setting `JAVA_HOME`:

```
# this is a work-around until there is a suitable runtime replacement 
# for dpkg-architecture for arch:all packages
# this function sets the variable OPENJDKS
find_openjdks()
{
        for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-*
        do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-common" ]
                then
                        OPENJDKS=$jvmdir
                fi
        done
        for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-*
        do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common" ]
                then
                        OPENJDKS="${OPENJDKS} ${jvmdir}"
                fi
        done
}
# 
OPENJDKS=""
find_openjdks
# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not
# defined in $DEFAULT)
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

# Look for the right JVM to use
for jdir in $JDK_DIRS; do
    if [ -r "$jdir/bin/java" -a -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
      JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
    fi
done
```

I commented all of that out (by adding `#` at the start of each line) and then added this.

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
export JAVA_HOME
```

Then simply restart tomcat with `sudo service tomcat7 restart` and a quick check in `/var/log/tomcat7/localhost.2017-01-13.log` (with your date in) will show if it is working.

Comment: thanks for your great help. i just wanted to do one more thing before I try your recommendation and it got me working in the end. check my solution above!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did in the end.

I uninstalled everything.

First I made sure that java8 is installed over instructions @iant provided belowe in his answer (How to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu 14.04?).

Then I installed Tomcat7 again following this tutorial: http://www.negengec.com/2014/09/run-geoserver-ubuntu-tomcat7/, except line `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` that I didnt use, plus in the file `sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat7` I have changed line with JAVA_HOME to: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052127/how-to-setup-tomcat7-in-ubuntu-14-04-so-that-it-uses-latest-jre-of-java-8-oracle).

Then I have just unzipped Geoserver file war.zip in var/lib/tomcat7/webapps and suddenly thing was working!

I hope I havent forgotten something and also, I hope some of the previous things didnt left behind during unistallation, in that case maybe something else was the cause of making this thing work!